# What is the perimeter of $\triangle ABC$?

Tags: geometry

What is the perimeter of $\triangle ABC$?

[image]

I am not sure if $AD=12$ or $AC=12$. The given answer is $P_{\triangle ABC}=42$ $cm$. I think we are supposed to use similar triangles and maybe $ABC$ and $DEC$ are similar, but I don't see why. Thank you in advance! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are not sure about the problem, how are we supposed to help you?

Comment: If you are unsure you should post the original problem.

Comment: @DavideTrono, if one can solve the problem, they can note if $AD=12$ or $AC=12$. Clearly, you cannnot. What do you mean how are you supposed to help me? I'll leave it here.

Comment: @JohnDouma, that is the original problem.

Comment: @Medi what if the problem has a solution in both cases?

Comment: I see what you mean. I would guess that $12$ is the length of $AD$ because of the color change.

Comment: @DavideTrono, I have given the answer for $P_{\triangle ABC}$. Is the perimeter $42$ in both the cases? No, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many triangles with visibly different perimeter that meet the description you provide:

[image]

(This picture is not drawn accurately to scale, but neither is the original. The segment of length $4$ is longer than that of length $5$.)